# ADFS 2.0 token expiration time

Tags: c#, adfs2.0, sts-securitytokenservice, federation

I am caching a token issued by a ADFS 2.0 on the client and use it several times when calling the service.

In the production environment I want to ensure that the token a client can cache expires after a few minutes. 
I have read that the token from the ADFS 2.0 expires after 10 hours, but I can't find a place where I can change the expiration time of a token for a relying party.

This is how I currently request a token from the STS:

```
WSTrustChannelFactory trustChannelFactory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(binding, http://adfs/adfs/services/trust/13/windows");

trustChannelFactory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
WSTrustChannel channel = (WSTrustChannel)trustChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
RequestSecurityToken rst = new RequestSecurityToken(WSTrust13Constants.RequestTypes.Issue);

rst.RequestDisplayToken = true;
rst.AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress("http://*****/IService);
rstr = null;
SecurityToken token = channel.Issue(rst, out rstr);
```

I have tried setting the WEB SSO time to two minutes, but it does not seem to have any affect.

**What is the correct place to configure the expiration time on the ADFS?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ADFS PowerShell extension module to perform this operation:

Use:

```
Set-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust –TargetName "Relying party name" –TokenLifeTime 5
```

to set expiration to 5 minutes.

Remember to load the ADFS PowerShell snap-in first, by running

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Adfs.PowerShell
```

Further documentation can be found here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-powershell-basics%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-help-using-windows-powershell%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was looking for a way to configure it via the UI, but it seems like using the powershell is the only way. Your links are very useful.